# Нет обмена сообщений между клиентом и сервером

Tags: java, sql, сокет, hibernate

В моей программе клиент и сервер взаимодействуют между собой с помощью текстовый команд, которые перемещаются с помощью потоков, но когда я посылаю команду, сервер её не воспринимает и замирает наглухо. При дебаге выяснил, что сообщения не посылаются через потоки. При этом нет никаких ошибок.

В логах сервера обнаружил такую запись, возможно дело в этом.

```
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

DAO.java

```
    package DataBase.Dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 20.04.2016.
 */
// Основа классов для работы с базой данных
public class DAO {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    private static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();
    private static final SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    protected DAO(){
    }

    //Метод для работы с сессиями
    public static Session getSession() {
        Session session = (Session) DAO.session.get();
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionfactory.openSession();
            DAO.session.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    //Начать транзакцию
    protected void begin(){
        getSession().beginTransaction();
    }

    //Подтвердить изменение
    protected void commit(){
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    //Откат изменений в случае сбоев
    protected void rollback(){
        try{
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            log.log(Level.WARNING,"Cannot rollback",e);
        }

        try{
            getSession().close();
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            log.log(Level.WARNING,"Cannot close",e);
        }
        DAO.session.set(null);
    }

    //Закрыть сессию
    protected void close(){
        getSession().close();
        DAO.session.set(null);
    }

}
```

Students.java

```
    package DataBase.Dao;

import DataBase.Tables.Students;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 20.04.2016.
 */
//DAO для работы со студентами
public class StudentsDAO extends DAO {

    //Создать студента
    public Students createStudent(String Firstname,String Lastname, String Group) throws Exception {
            try {
                begin();
                Students students = new Students(Firstname,Lastname,Group);
                getSession().save(students);
                commit();
                close();
                return students;
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                rollback();
                throw new Exception("Could not create student " + " ", e);
            }
        }

    public List<Students> retrieveAllStudent() throws Exception{
        try {
            begin();
            List<Students> students = getSession().createQuery("from Students ").list();
            commit();
            close();
            return students;
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            rollback();
            throw new Exception("Could not get students" + e );
        }
    }

    public void updateStudent(int studentId,String FirstName,String LastName, String Group) throws Exception {
        try { begin();
        Students stud =(Students)getSession().get(Students.class,studentId);
        stud.setFirstName(FirstName);
        stud.setLastName(LastName);
        stud.setGroup(Group);
        getSession().update(stud);
        commit();
        close();
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            rollback();
            try {
                throw new Exception("Could not update student " + studentId);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Удалить студента
    public void deleteStudent(int studentid) throws Exception{
        try {
            begin();
            Students stud = (Students) getSession().get(Students.class,studentid);
            getSession().delete(stud);
            commit();
            close();
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            rollback();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete student " + studentid);
        }
    }

}
```

Server.java

```
package DataBase.Server;

import DataBase.Dao.StudentsDAO;
import DataBase.Tables.Students;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 17.04.2016.
 */
public class Server {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    private static Session session;
    private static Transaction tx;

    public static boolean checkstud(String finame,String laname,String gro){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List students = session.createQuery("from Students ").list();
        for (Iterator iterator = students.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            Students stud = (Students) iterator.next();
            if(finame.equals(stud.getFirstName())&&laname.equals(stud.getLastName())&&gro.equals(stud.getGroup())){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 5555; //Серверный порт

        try {
            ServerSocket sv = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client");

            Socket sock = sv.accept();
            System.out.println("Client is ready!");
            System.out.println();

            boolean checkCopy=false;

            StudentsDAO studDAO = new StudentsDAO();

            //Создание потоков ввода-вывода, а также обертка для данных
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

            String line = String.valueOf(1);
            String stud = null;

            BufferedReader keyBoard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while(line != "ex"){
                System.out.println("i wait command");
                line = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("I get command");
                if (line.equals("cr")){
                    String finame = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get FirstName");
                    String laname = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get LastName");
                    String gro = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get Group");
                    checkCopy = checkstud(finame,laname,gro);
                    if(checkCopy){
                    Students stude = studDAO.createStudent(finame,laname,gro);
                    dos.writeUTF("Student is created succesfully");
                    }
                    else{
                        dos.writeUTF("Student is already exist");
                    }
                }

                if (line.equals("rd")){
                    List<Students> stun = studDAO.retrieveAllStudent();
                    String s;
                    int i = stud.length();
                    dos.write(i);
                    for (Students sud : stun){
                        s = sud.getFirstName();
                        dos.writeUTF(s);
                        s = sud.getLastName();
                        dos.writeUTF(s);
                        s = sud.getGroup();
                        dos.writeUTF(s);
                    }
                }

                if (line.equals("ud")){
                    checkCopy = false;
                    String ids = dis.readUTF();
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(ids);
                    System.out.println("Get id");
                    String finame = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get FirstName");
                    String laname = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get LastName");
                    String gro = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Get Group");
                    studDAO.updateStudent(id, finame, laname, gro);
                    dos.writeUTF("Student succesfully updated");
                }
                if (line.equals("dt")){
                    String ids = dis.readUTF();
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(ids);
                    studDAO.deleteStudent(id);
                    dos.writeUTF("Student succesfully deleted");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something Wrong with server part");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Client.java

```
package DataBase.Client;

import DataBase.Dao.StudentsDAO;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 17.04.2016.
 */
public class Client {

    public static void menuShow(){
        System.out.println("Hello using this program you can create, look or delete students from database.");
        System.out.println("Please type one of the next commands");
        System.out.println("1.type 'cr' to create a student ");
        System.out.println("2.type 'rd' to retrieve all students");
        System.out.println("3.type 'ud' to update a student");
        System.out.println("4.type 'dt' to delete a student");
        System.out.println("0.type 'ex' to exit");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int serverPort = 5555; //Серверный порт
        String IpAddress = "127.0.0.1"; //IP адрес
        StudentsDAO studDAO = new StudentsDAO();

        try {
            InetAddress ipAdrr = InetAddress.getByName(IpAddress); //Установить интернет адрес
            System.out.println("Your socket is ipAddress " + ipAdrr + " server socket " + serverPort);
            Socket sv = new Socket(ipAdrr, serverPort); //Создание сокетов с серверным портом и интернет адресом
            System.out.println("Client socket is ready!");

            //Создание потоков ввода-вывода, а также обертка для данных
            InputStream is = sv.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = sv.getOutputStream();

            ObjectOutputStream odos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

            //Ввод данных с клавиатуры
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;
            String stud = null;
            menuShow();
            line = buf.readLine();
            while (!line.equals("ex")) {
                if (line.equals("cr")){
                    dos.writeUTF(line);
                    System.out.println("Enter FirstName");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    System.out.println("Enter LastName");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    System.out.println("Enter Group");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    dis.readUTF();
                }
                if (line.equals("rd")){
                    dos.writeUTF(line);
                    int i = dis.read();
                    for (int j = 1;j<=i;j++){
                        String s = dis.readUTF();
                        System.out.print(s);
                        String d = dis.readUTF();
                        System.out.print(d);
                        String f = dis.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(f);
                    }
                }
                if (line.equals("ud")) {
                    dos.writeUTF("ud");
                    System.out.println("choose the 'ID' of student that you want update");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    System.out.println("Enter FirstName");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    System.out.println("Enter LastName");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    System.out.println("Enter Group");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    dis.readUTF();
                }
                if (line.equals("dt")){
                    dos.writeUTF("dt");
                    System.out.println("choose the 'ID' of student that you want delete");
                    stud = buf.readLine();
                    dos.writeUTF(stud);
                    dis.readUTF();
                }
                menuShow();
                line = buf.readLine();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Students.java

```
package DataBase.Tables;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 20.04.2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Students {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String LastName;

    @Column(name = "Groupstud")
    private String Group;

    public Students(String FirstName,String LastName,String Group){
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Group = Group;
    }

    public Students() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return Group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        Group = group;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
        <mapping class="DataBase.Tables.Students"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Логи сервера

```
июн 03, 2016 6:18:52 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
июн 03, 2016 6:18:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
июн 03, 2016 6:18:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud]
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Fri Jun 03 18:18:53 MSK 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
июн 03, 2016 6:18:53 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Waiting for a client
Client is ready!

июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud]
июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Fri Jun 03 18:19:05 MSK 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
июн 03, 2016 6:19:05 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
i wait command
```

Логи Клиента

```
июн 03, 2016 6:19:02 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
июн 03, 2016 6:19:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
июн 03, 2016 6:19:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud]
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
июн 03, 2016 6:19:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Fri Jun 03 18:19:03 MSK 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
июн 03, 2016 6:19:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Your socket is ipAddress /127.0.0.1 server socket 5555
Client socket is ready!
Hello using this program you can create, look or delete students from database.
Please type one of the next commands
1.type 'cr' to create a student 
2.type 'rd' to retrieve all students
3.type 'ud' to update a student
4.type 'dt' to delete a student
0.type 'ex' to exit

cr
Enter FirstName
dfgdfgdfg
Enter LastName
dfgdgdfs
Enter Group
asdasd
```

Comment: ну попробуйте `flush()` вызвать после `writeUTF`

Comment: Нет, это не работает. Сервер должен был прочитать отправленную команду. но так и не прочитал

Comment: уберите в коде клиента `ObjectOutputStream odos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);`, похоже он сразу при создании пишет в поток четыре волшебных байта, а `readUTF` на сервере воспринимает их, как длину входящей строки.

Comment: Вы - волшебник! Никогда бы не додумался, можете рассказать побольше об этих волшебных байтах, либо кинуть ссылку на материал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что конструктор [`ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java/#240) сразу записывает в `out` два двухбайтных целых `STREAM_MAGIC = 0xaced` и `STREAM_VERSION`. Эти числа нужны, чтобы принимающий `ObjectInputStream` сразу мог понять, что в потоке будут подходящие данные, и определить версию протокола.

При этом [`DataInputStream.readUTF`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/DataInputStream.java#588) воспринимает первые два байта, как длину входящей строки в байтах, и пытается их все прочитать в массив. 0xACED = 44269, столько в потоке нет, поэтому выполнение останавливается.

Для решения проблемы нужно либо убрать создание `ObjectOutputStream`, либо с обеих сторон использовать `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` благо `writeUTF/readUTF` они тоже умеют.

Ссылки приведены на [grepcode.com], но исходные коды стандартной библиотеки удобнее смотреть в IDE.